# How to load multiple YAML structures from a single file using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

Using these:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator;
```

I have a file with two YAML structures inside

```
version: 1.0
time:
  day: 20
  second: 15
  minute: 39
  hour: 19
  weekday: 4
  month: 1
  year: 1999
ironman: true
rulesets:
  - Xcom1Ruleset
  - XcomUtil_Always_Daytime
  - XcomUtil_Skyranger_Weapon_Slot
  - XcomUtil_Starting_Defensive_Improved_Base
  - XcomUtil_Pistol_Auto_Shot
---
alienStrategy:
(...)
```

I've tried this:

```
directives = mapper.readValue(fileIn, Directives.class);
savegame = mapper.readValue(fileIn, Savegame.class);
```

But I receive this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (class app.Savegame), not marked as ignorable (24 known properties: "globeZoom", "bases", "monthsPassed", "warned", "discovered", "incomes", "rng", "funds", "globeLat", "maintenance", "expenditures", "ufos", "graphCountryToggles", "ids", "alienStrategy", "difficulty", "researchScores", "graphRegionToggles", "globeLon", "regions", "alienMissions", "graphFinanceToggles", "countries", "deadSoldiers"])
 at [Source: C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\in.txt; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: app.Savegame["name"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:833)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1096)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1467)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1445)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2731)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

The Directive.java component it's mapped Ok, but Savegame.java (with alienStrategy and more properties) tries to map, it fails.

Please feel free to edit this question in order to clarify it to other users.

Comment: I have edited the question with a minimal YAML file, with the "---" structure separation mark. (...) means that there is more text from the second YAML structure. Oh, sorry, P.D. is a Latin expression that means (more information). I'm going to delete it because it's not English.

Comment: I would use P.S. (post scriptum) for that. Although on [so] it is better to just integrate the text (or if it is less relevant, provide it as a comment on your own post).

Comment: Can you show the expected mapping? Ie, what goes into `Directives`, what would be in `Savegame`?